# Store file path chosen in dialog box Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have written some code in Excel VBA which calls a macro in another workbook. The other workbook's VBA code is locked, but I can still run the macro itself. The macro does some calculations, then brings up a dialog box so the user can choose where to save the results.

After running this macro, I need the file path for the results file (to use the results in further calculations).

Is there any way to store the file path chosen by the user? Or alternatively, is there any way of automatically putting a specific file path in the dialog box to save to?

Comment: You can unlock the VBA code quite easily even though you don't know the password. Just google it. Maybe it can helpful for you...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't unlock the code because it would go against our license agreement. Good to know that it's possible to unlock code without a password though, in any case!

Comment: Show the code that prompts user for *results* path. In that dialog such a path is captured.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the file path directly. One workaround could be to use `Application.RecentFiles`(`Application.RecentFiles(i).Path`/`Application.RecentFiles(i).Name`). Unfortunately I don't have excel installed on my PC is I can't test if it really works.

If this workaround don't work, that there is no other way to get the file path. You would have to ask the user to select the file.